# Concat two macros in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to concatenate two values each defined as macro. At this moment I've:

```
#define VAL1 @"im/"
#define VAL2 @"test"
#define GLUE_IN(x,y) (x ## y)
#define GLUE(x,y) GLUE_IN(x,y)
```

when I use it in code:

```
[array addObject:GLUE(VAL1, VAL2)];
```

it produces me an error: Pasting formed '"im/"@', an invalid preprocessing token

I'm aware that it may be solved by:

```
#define GLUE(x,y) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",x,y]
```

however I'm curious is it possible to achieve this same result using preprocessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`##` concatenates tokens, not strings, which causes an invalid resulting token, and in this case is entirely un-necessary since `@"im/" @"test"` - being compile time string constants - will be appended anyway. Just do;

```
#define GLUE_IN(x,y) (x y)
```

...which will result in

```
[array addObject:@"im/" @"test"]
```

...and things should work well.

Comment: Sorry but I tried this before ## approach. This produces incorrect result. It will compile but when you look into array you will see first string only (@"im/").

Comment: Edit: After your post I recheck and it works. I probably made some typo. Now it works as it should, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna ask why you ever need it, but here is possible solution:

```
#define VAL1 im
#define VAL2 test
#define STR2(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR2(x)
#define GLUE_IN(a,b) a##b
#define GLUE(x,y) GLUE_IN(x,y)
```

…

```
NSString *val1 = @(STR(GLUE(VAL1, VAL2)));
NSString *val2 = @"another " @"test";
NSLog(@"%@, %@", val1, val2);
```

It gives you

> **imtest, anothertest**

However, you'll have some troubles with a slash sign. If I were you, I'd prefer another way.